# JUnit equivalent to NUnit Assert.Inconclusive?

Tags: java, junit, nunit

I'm a .Net developer and am brand new to Java and JUnit.

I'm used to using the NUnit `Assert.Inconclusive()` method in certain situations, but I haven't come across the same thing in JUnit.

I poked around the JUnit website as well as a bit on Google and stackoverflow. At a glance, it looks like there's no equivalent in JUnit to the NUnit `Assert.Inconclusive()` method.

Is that really the case?

Comment: In Java, we use `Assert.fail()`, maybe with a message like "still to implement" for indicating work in progress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use Inconclusive in NUnit to assert when a precondition for the test is not met.

For example, if your test requires reading a file then doing something with that input, and maybe the file is missing or the user running the test doesn't have permission to read the file - the test should not fail per-se, because there may be nothing wrong with your algorithm, there is just something wrong with the way the environment in which the test is being run.

Another use case is if you want to write an integration test that does stuff with a database.  If the database is not running or can't be connected to, your test is really inconclusive, not a failure - it never even got off the ground to run due to environment issues.

For this, I would suggest that @Ignore is not what you want, because that makes your test not run at all.  Instead you want to use are the various [Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [assumptions](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html), or throw your own [`AssumptionViolatedException`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/AssumptionViolatedException.html).

```
public static void inconclusive() {
    throw new AssumptionViolatedException("Inconclusive");
}
```

This is intended to show that the test result cannot be relied upon and will show the test as ignored in IntelliJ.

> A failed assumption does not mean the code is broken, but that the test provides no useful information. The default JUnit runner treats tests with failing assumptions as ignored. Custom runners may behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `JUnit5` with `IntelliJ`, and to make it work (from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43209183/2971847)) I had to do the following.

First:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions;
```

Then in your test method:

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions
Assumptions.assumeTrue(false, "Inconclusive");
```

Feel free to change the `"Inconclusive"` message to something more explicative, for example giving the reason why.

Answer (score -3):

I do not know NUnit.

But if you want to fail the test, you can use [Asset.fail](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#fail(java.lang.String))

Or is there any reason to use this method?

Comment: There are a few cases where asserting inconclusive is handy, but it's hardly a necessity. I tend to mostly assert inconclusive to denote tests that are stubbed, but are not fully implemented yet. There are other uses, but this is the most common way I use it.

Comment: When my test is not complete, I'm use to ignore it with a text message explaining it's pending : http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html

Comment: Cool, that's probably the way I will accomplish this in JUnit. Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopheDufour I found this helpful, but the real answer is in your comment: JUnit Ignore is about equivalent to NUnit Inconclusive. I suggest adding another answer or editing the one you have. (I know it's old, but SO is supposed to be a living resource.)